# How do I put a brick wall where an exterior window is?

Tags: walls, windows, garage, brick

I have a detached garage with fairly large sliding windows (previous owner installed these) with a brick exterior.  I want to remove the windows and close up the wall with bricks.  What do I need to do to accomplish this?  Will I need to remove some of the brick surrounding the windows?  I expect I need to be able to put up some exterior wall material plus some moisture barrier.  I'm new to DIY home improvement so any input would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Tom

Comment: Is this something you are planning to do, or are you going to get help on things like the bricklaying?

Comment: Are you in a region that sometimes has significant earthquakes?  For example, within 100 miles of the Pacific Ocean, within 100 miles of an active volcano, within 100 miles of a young mountain range, or within 500 miles of Saint Louis?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to tie in the new brickwork. Either carefully remove the 'half' bricks up each side of the opening and build into them as you go (but the mortar will always 'jump out' at you in the 'toothings').

Or, build inside the opening as it is and use a propriety metal tie in bracket and a screw or two. You'll need one each side every few courses (some go every 3 and some every 6). You have the option to set this new brickwork panel back (or forward I guess), 10mm works okay. This has the effect of making the new brickwork look like a feature panel and a little more 'deliberate' than going flush. Some folks leave the joint around the new brickwork empty and fill it with a caulk and backer foam to remove the risk of the mortar cracking around the new panel. In my experience if the brickwork is built up in warm/good weather this is not likely to be much of a problem.